# Cucumber JVM cannot find the steps defined

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

When I run to run this test with a feature it complains it cannot find the steps. I have tried defining them in Java 8 style, and Java 7 style and using IntelliJ to generate the steps into a `MyStepdefs` class but it cannot find them.

I am using version 1.2.4 of cucumber-java8 and cucumber-junit.

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.DataTable;
import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java8.En;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        monochrome = true,
        glue = {"com.mycom.core.agg.RunCukesTest"})
public class RunCukesTest implements En {

    public RunCukesTest() {
        Given("^I have PriceLevels$", (DataTable arg1) -> {
        });

        And("^I have a TradeRequest$", (DataTable arg1) -> {
        });

        Then("^I should get these LegRequests$", (DataTable arg1) -> {
        });
    }
}
```

running the test prints

```
Running com.mycom.core.agg.RunCukesTest

1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
3 Steps (3 undefined)
0m0.000s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

Given("^I have PriceLevels$", (DataTable arg1) -> {
.. rest deleted ...
```

Running the feature file from IntelliJ give much the same error.

Answer (score 1):

While we couldn't figure out what the cause was, create a new maven project with a minimum of dependencies "fixed" the problem.  We didn't need to change the code.

Comment: The problem you faced was a classpath that didn't contain the expected steps. 

Creating a Maven project will also create a classpath that contains features and steps if you locate them in src/test/resources/<your package>/*.feature and src/test/java/<package>/*.java. 

The expected result is that the steps will be found. As you got.

Comment: @ThomasSundberg The paths of the features and steps is the same in the first project as the second.  I even used the idea to put in the steps and the plugin said that it could find a match. It appears to have been a conflict with a dependency as even if I used examples from the github/cucumber I got the same error until I created a new project.